# Oracle: Select values and join result from multiple rows in one with seperat cells

Tags: oracle, select, pivot

I have to create a select Statement, which bring me a multiple row result in one. 
For better understanding here my table

```
Id |  Name  |  Typ  |  Date
---------------------------------
1  |  John  |  200  |  2019-01-05 
2  |  John  |  201  |  2016-09-01 
3  |  John  |  202  |  2020-11-03 
4  |  John  |  601  |  1955-03-03
```

Now i‘m looking for a select which brings me the following result

```
Id  |  Name  |  200         |  201         |  202         |  601
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  John  |  2019-01-05  |  2016-09-01  |  2020-11-03  |  1955-03-03
```

The only Option i found was the LISTAGG Function, but with it, the result is a concatenatet String. 
I want to use the result in a c# application, because I don‘t like to select an sort in c#.

Comment: You are looking for `PIVOT` - but this is typically much easier done in your application than in SQL.

Comment: See [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference - SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702), "Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT: Examples" section.